# Why use clustering + external measure for validation, instead of supervised learning?

Tags: validation, unsupervised-learning, supervised-learning

Lets say I have set of genes in individuals and I will use clustering to find groups of individuals with similar genes and then I will check how these groups express itself in form of some disease. I will find that my clusters found by unsupervised learning are good predictor for some disease, and I will conclude that my clusters are therefore valid. This types of studies are not uncommon, but if I have external measures that I am trying to predict, why don't use supervised learning instead? What is point of those kinds of unsupervised studies? Am I missing something?

Comment: As you suggest, this is *almost always* a bad idea. These kinds of schemes often arise when people that lack a statistics and/or machine learning background design the analyses.

Comment: `but if I have external measures that I am trying to predict, why don't use supervised learning instead` These two types of studies are two different aims. One aim (supervised) is the wilful direct prediction. The other (via clustering) can be the indirect, deliberately "blind" prediction. Both approaches are valid - in their own contexts.

Comment: can you elaborate?